# Code Contract violation for projecting into an anonymous type using IQueryable

Tags: c#-4.0, iqueryable, code-contracts

I'm having a hard time understanding why I am getting a code contract violation on the following piece of code:

```
     // servicequery is of type System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<DividendData>
     // therefore implements IQueryable
     var serviceQuery = CreateDataService().DividendData;
     Contract.Assume(serviceQuery != null);
     Contract.Assume(serviceQuery.Any());
     var data = serviceQuery
        .Select(div => new {I = 2});
```

The violation is: `CodeContracts: requires unproven: constructor != null` right on the assignment.

If I change this code to the following, the violation goes away:

```
  class resulttype
  {
     public int I { get; set; }
  }


  var serviceQuery = CreateDataService().DividendData;
  Contract.Assume(serviceQuery != null);
  Contract.Assume(serviceQuery.Any());
  var data = serviceQuery
     .Select(div => new resulttype() {I = 2});
```

My question is 'why?'.

Comment: Could you provide the exception stack trace? Which of the 2 assignments throws it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it need an actual class as a contract. What you can do is:

```
var serviceQuery = CreateDataService().DividendData;
Contract.Assume(serviceQuery != null);
Contract.Assume(serviceQuery.Any());
var data = serviceQuery.ToList().Select(div => {I = 2});
```

Anyway, it's very weird what you are doing there...

Comment: Also, it seems you are executing the service twice, maybe you'll want to put the result in a variable and then check if it has elements

Comment: So I'm not getting why it's weird either? I am trying to select a subset of data (specific columns only) from the DividendData WCF Data Service.